# Docfx not build and output other path

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, documentation-generation, docfx

There are two responsibilities;
before the first problem

my project hierarchy [this](https://ibb.co/hVtzqG)

and I want for each project code to documentation for this i use docfx.
first problem;
I don't want the building code to be rebuilt.
ex.

```
docfx ./docs/docfx.json --serve -> doing the build
```

second problem;
I want documentation result give me another path. 
ex.

```
C:\Users\ahmet\Documentation
```

code

`docfx docfx ./docs/docfx.json -o  -C:\Users\ahmet\Documentation > not working`

and my docfx.json [configration](https://ybin.me/p/3251db423d7756eb#R2hEqP4qHGnnnkkwznp9ltkVl3oR5BTfIcrH5LGNrME=)

Thanks

Solution for 2 questions
if you want to generate document different output path.

`docfx init`

`_site in place of, output path as C:/Users/AhmetPC/Desktop/SourceCode`

or this 
`docfx.exe docfx.json -o C:/Users/AhmetPC/Desktop/SourceCode`

it creates for us this path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep the default output folder `_site` of docfx, you can try `docfx serve  ./docs/_site` for the first question.